# How do I get multiple values from checkboxes in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, checkbox

I want to get values of a multiple select check box using `request.POST['xzy']` as a list.
Here is my model and template code.

**My Model**

```
class Recommend(models.Model):
  user=models.ForeignKey(User)
  book=models.ForeignKey(BookModel)
  friends=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="recommended")
```

**My Template**

```
{% for friend in friends %}

<input type="checkbox" name="recommendations" id="option{{friend.id}}" value={{friend.username}} />
<label for="option{{friend.id}}"><b>{{friend.username}}</b></label><br />

{% endfor %}
```

**My View code**

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
  recommendations=request.POST['recommendations']
```

Here I want 'recommendations' to be a list containing all friend ids but here it is just getting overwritten and only contains the value that got assigned in the last for loop iteration. How can I solve this problem. Need help desperately. Thank You.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
request.POST.getlist('recommendations')
```

Comment: @KiranRuthR you dont use getlist in template, you use in views.py.

Comment: but i got an issue when i use .getlist '  'id' expected a number but got ['10', '11', '12'].  '

Answer (score 2):

```
if not request.POST.has_key(strName):
      return ""    
  if request.POST[strName]:
      return ','.join(request.POST.getlist(strName))          
  else:
      return ""
```