# Passing checkboxes values to view in django

Tags: django, checkbox, django-templates, django-views

I have a table with some database data

```
<table id="id_list_table" class="table table-condensed">
<caption>Inputs list</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th id="input">Input</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="fbody">
    {%for input in InputsAll%}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ input.input }}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{% url 'edit' %}?input_num={{input.id}}" id="edit">edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="{% url 'delete' %}?input_num={{input.id}}" id="remove">remove</a>
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="{% url 'resolve' %}?input_num={{input.id}}"id="resolve">resolve</a>
                <input type="checkbox" name="inputs" id="option{{input.id}}" value={{input.id}} />
            </td>
        </tr>
    {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and i want to add a checkbox to every field and pass checked data's id to view and make group action instead of removing items one by one. 
i added this checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inputs" id="option{{input.id}}" value={{input.id}} />
```

and how should i pass all checked values to view? Does it work this way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359238/how-do-i-get-multiple-values-from-checkboxes-in-django

Comment: You may need to put that inside a form tag and ensure that it is sent via POST.

Comment: @cdvv7788 I found this question, but i'm not sure how he passed data to view. And what should i put into form tag? All the table or just checkbox input?

Comment: Read a little about forms first (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp). When you submit a form, every input is sent via the selected method, so you need to add all the checkboxes if you want to send a list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        #gives list of id of inputs 
        list_of_input_ids=request.POST.getlist('inputs')
```

Hope this solves pretty much of your problem.Check out this link 
[Checkboxes for a list of items like in Django admin interface](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Checkboxes-for-a-list-of-items-like-in-Django-admin-interface-td3142240.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But i'm not completely understand how removal should be triggered.

Comment: once you get the object.id u can do a group action
'for x in list_of_inputs_ids:
y = Model.objects.get(pk=x)
y.delete()'