# Receiving Checkbox Values Using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, jinja2

I have the following checkbox definitions:

```
{% for member in team_profile %}
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxes" value="{{ member.user_id }}">{{ member.first_name }}</label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Where team_profile just contains a bunch of member names. So the I would like to get the `value={{member.userid}}` stuff.

So for my jquery i have:

```
var myCheckboxes = new Array();
$("input:checked").each(function() {
    data['myCheckboxes[]'].push($(this).val());
});

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'createEvent/',
    data:{
        name: name,
        myCheckboxes: myCheckboxes,
    }
});
```

So I want to collect all the values and store them in an array called `myCheckboxes`. But I am getting an error `data is not defined`. Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks,
Andy

EDIT:

Okay, I made the following changes:

```
var myCheckboxes = new Array();
$("input:checked").each(function() {
    data['myCheckboxes[]'].push($(this).val());
});

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'createEvent/',
    data:{
        name: name,
        myCheckboxes: myCheckboxes,
    }
});
```

and in my `views.py`:

```
def createEvent(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        member = request.POST.get('myCheckboxes')
        print(member)
```

But when I print out member, `None` gets outputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple suggestions...

For one, avoid using duplicate `id="checkboxes"` attributes, for example by using use `name="checkboxes"`:

```
{% for member in team_profile %}
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="{{ member.user_id }}">{{ member.first_name }}</label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Also, the correct way to add data to an array is by using `myCheckboxes.push(...)`:

```
var myCheckboxes = new Array();
$("input:checked").each(function() {
    myCheckboxes.push($(this).val()); // changed this line
});

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'createEvent/',
    data:{
        name: name,
        myCheckboxes: myCheckboxes,
    }
});
```

Lastly, get the values on the server as follows:

```
def createEvent(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        member = request.POST.getlist('myCheckboxes[]')
        print(member)
```

Comment: I get the MultiValueDictKeyError: "'myCheckboxes'". Is this because there are many ID that are the same?

Comment: I changed it to member = request.POST.get('myCheckboxes') but, it returns a None

Comment: You may need to use `request.POST.getlist('myCheckboxes[]')` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359238/how-do-i-get-multiple-values-from-checkboxes-in-django - with regard to the duplicate `id="checkboxes"` attributes, you should change that to `name="checkboxes"`.

Comment: Cool... It has to do with the way that jQuery.param() serializes arrays.  In any case, glad this works for you. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/