# Django extract field form html

Tags: django, forms

I have a html page that returns data in a form. The forms is a multiple choice checkbox field with `"name=states1"`. When I run print(vars(self)) in my forms.py I see that the data is there `['MD', 'WV', 'WY']` (see below) however, when I try to extract it with `print(self.data['states1'])` I just get 'WY' and `print(len(self.data['states1']))` returns 2.

```
{'instance': <AA: AAobject>, '_validate_unique': False, 'is_bound': True, 'data': <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['AAAAA']: ['1'], 'states1': ['MD', 'WV', 'WY'], 'states': [''], 'price': ['2.00'], 'user': ['1', '1']}>, ...
```

However, when I run

```
import json
print(json.dumps(self.data, indent=2))
```

I get the following output

```
    {
  "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "AAAAA",
  "roles": "1",
  "states1": "WY",
  "states": "",
  "price": "2.00",
  "user": "1"
}
```

The data is just gone. Why is my data being restricted to the last field, when I can clearly see it when looking at vars?

forms.py

```
class UserProfileChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
states = forms.CharField(widget=USStateSelect(), initial='TX', required=False)

class Meta:
    model = SkilledLaborer
    fields = ['user','roles','travel_flag','price','states']


def clean_states(self):
    print('states')
    states = self.cleaned_data['states']
    print(type(vars(self)))
    print(vars(self).keys())
    print(vars(self))
    print(self.data.keys())
    print(self.data['states1'])
    print(len(self.data['states1']))

    import json
    print(json.dumps(self.data, indent=2))

    try:
        self.data['states1']
    except:
        pass

    return states
```

Comment: could you post form.py?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get multiple values from checkboxes in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359238/how-do-i-get-multiple-values-from-checkboxes-in-django)

Comment: From what I understand, you don't use 'if request.method == 'POST':' when you have a class based view.