# How to correctly filter a QuerySet based on a form MultipleChoice field?

Tags: python, django, python-requests, request

This is how I have defined my form:

```
class TaskFilterForm(forms.Form):
    status = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=PLAN_STATUS,
    )
```

And I'm trying to get my QuerySet filtered like this:

```
class MyTasksView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'my-tasks.html'
    context_object_name = 'tasks'
    object_list = Task.objects.all()
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context                    
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['filter_form'] = TaskFilterForm(self.request.GET)
        return context
    
    
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs): 
        print(self.request.GET)      
        qs = Task.objects.filter(assignee=self.request.user)
        status = self.request.GET.get('status')
        if status:
            qs = qs.filter(status__in=status)
        return qs
    
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter_form'] = TaskFilterForm(self.request.POST)
        print('MyTaskView.request.POST', self.request.POST)
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

It is correctly filtering just for an item, but I'd like it to filter, say, including status 0 and 1, when both are selected.

How should I correct this?

Comment: can you clarify about this "It is correctly filtering just for an item, but I'd like it to filter, say, including status 0 and 1, when both are selected."?

Comment: Sure... currently when I select more than one checkbox, it is not including both in the the filtered queryset, but only restricring it by the option that does not have any matching record. It seems it is taking just one of the options into account instead of both,

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at this question regarding https://stackoverflow.com/a/4359300/14602684multiple checkbox values

as for the filter to fetch results with more than one value, do the following

```
from django.db.models import Q
...
Task.objects.filter(Q(assignee=self.request.user, status__in=status1) | Q(assignee=self.request.user, status__in=status2))
```

or

```
qs.filter(Q(status__in=status1) | Q(status__in=status2))
```

without using the Q

```
qs = qs.filter(status__in=status1)
qs2 = qs.filter(status__in=status2)
qs.union(qs2)
```

each status is a different checkbox value so I don't know how you will represent them in your code ex: status[0], status[1]!
the important thing is the use of the filter for multiple values

reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/

Answer (score 0):

I have just got it working!

Just needed to replace request.get by request.getlist. As it returns a list of items, the "in" filter works just fine!

```
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        status = self.request.GET.getlist('status')
        print('Status:', status)
        qs = Task.objects.filter(assignee=self.request.user)
        if status:
            qs = qs.filter(status__in=status)       
        return qs
```